# Bundle error when deploy with capistrano(rbenv)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, rbenv

I use capistrano to deploy my rails app to my vps. And i have problem when `cap deploy update`.

The error message is like this:

```
 ** [out :: 1] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: 1] 
 ** [out :: 1] /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
 ** [out :: 1] 
 ** [out :: 1] 
 ** [out :: 1] Gem files will remain installed in /home/deployer/apps/get-real/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/raindrops-0.10.0 for inspection.
 ** [out :: 1] 
 ** [out :: 1] Results logged to /home/deployer/apps/get-real/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/raindrops-0.10.0/ext/raindrops/gem_make.out
 ** [out :: 1] 
 ** [out :: 1] An error occurred while installing raindrops (0.10.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
 ** [out :: 1] 
 ** [out :: 1] Make sure that `gem install raindrops -v '0.10.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I try to run commend `gem install raindrops -v '0.10.0'` on my server and it succeed. But when I run `cap deploy:update` again, it fails with the same error message.

I had this problem before and I tried some method and it worked. But now I forgot what I did to make it work...

Comment: What is the OS of your server? As it said in [gem description](http://rubygems.org/gems/raindrops), it depends on POSIX shared memory, so for example here on my Win64 machine bulding native extensions fails with `checking for mmap() in sys/mman.h... no mmap() not found`. Other reason may be not having build tools (make, gcc) in PATH. Are you sure you successfully run `gem install raindrops` **from the same user you deploy from**?

Comment: @NIA I use ubuntu as my server OS. And i do use the same user to run `gem install rainsdrops`.

Comment: And what does '/home/deployer/apps/get-real/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/raindrops-0.10.0/ext/raindrops/gem_make.out' say?

Comment: @cthulhu just `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I just went to `/home/deployer/apps/get-real/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/` and run `gem install raindrops -v '0.10.0'`